# How to enable String.format template for automatic toString() generation in IntelliJ Java?

Tags: java, templates, intellij-idea, tostring, string.format

As above, how to enable `toString()` automatic generation in '`String.format`' style in IntelliJ IDEA? (Java language)

I was looking for templates but can't find any, no answer in jetbrains docs as well.

Answer (score 0):

In *Code>Insert Live Template* whose shortcut is *CTRL+J*

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but's not the answer for my question. I ment automatic generation of toString() for fields with 'String.format' formatting. So I need to enable it in intelliJ as in the picture. Or i just don't understand how to generate them with live template...

[image: generate toString step1]

[image: choosing a template step 2]

In template section i don't have String.format template and i need to add it. In eclipse it's in default but here not.